# JSF JDBC realm form based authentication search by username and email address

Tags: java, security, jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am using Glassfish JDBC realm for the authentication of users, so authentication process is managed by its container. I need to use userid/email address as a username. Both userid and email address has different column in postgres user table and i am using JPA. In short user can be logged in by its userid or email.

I have written programatically login and logout methods. login has only two arguments

`request.login(username, password);`

After searching on google i have a doubt that i have to use somehow user provider which i don't know.

[image]

in Below figure i can just enter USERID by i would like to have EMAIL column as well.
[image]

**any suggestions/hint/idea would be appreciable.**

Comment: ok functional requirement: user should have opportunity to use its user id or email in the username text box. In glassfish web console we have to explicitly define the username, but in my case there should be two columns in the database table for authentication. how to define or implement this type of authentication. i have already used authentication process by just username and password and worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are serveral approaches you can take:

1. If you aren't interested in the username but just the fact that the user authenticated correctly, you can use a database view unioning userid and email into one column:

   CREATE VIEW vUsers AS
   SELECT userid, password from Users where userid IS NOT NULL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT email, password from Users where email IS NOT NULL

   (note this syntax is not expected to work)
   You now can redirect the JDBC configuration to that view.

   This is probably not the way you wan't to go. In most cases, after authentication some decisions are made based on the login name. This can now be either email or userid. An Unique login name for the same person is better.
2. Process the username before login via [`HttpServletRequest#login`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):
   Because userid and email usually are of different formats, you can decide, which one the user provided at the login form.

   - If it is a userid, you can use the `HttpServletRequest#login` method directly.
   - If it is an email you can lookup the userid for the email and then use  `HttpServletRequest#login`.

   This way. you can not use glassfish form login anymore, but you always end up with the userid as login name.

   See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gircj/index.html
3. Write your own login module:
   You could write your own JAAS Login Module. There are several tutorials out there.
   Nevertheless, this would basically boil down to distinguish between email and userid, so method 2 should suffice.

Comment: Thanks alot saved my life. :) I also thought about pre process the username but didn't clicked in my mind :)